# try after for in python

Tags: python, try-catch

Here is the code:

```
aList = []
for p in anotherList:
  aList.append(p)
  try:
    k=p.someMethod()
    aList.append(k) #getting error here
  except someException:
    continue
 return aList
```

I am getting "Global name error--aList not defined.Why so?

Comment: Is this the exact code that you're using? The indentation is off.

Comment: its not the exact code.?But similar to which I am using now.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong other than the indentation.  If no one else spots anything either, then maybe you can try to make a fully reproducible sample of the problem?  (I suggest this because it looks like you're almost there already.)  For instance, define anotherList at the beginning of your sample with dummy data and use real methods for someMethod and a real exception for someException.  If your carefully constructed sample doesn't exhibit the problem then you're halfway to understanding what went wrong -- and if it does, you can post the sample and be certain of finding help.

Comment: Post the exact code that you're using.

Comment: Well, this is a snippet, and provided it is in the context of a function, it alone should have no problems (as long as the `return` indentation level is fixed).  So could you provide code that is more directly matching the code that is having problems?

Comment: I am so sorry.It was just a silly spelling mistake.:(.

Comment: @Blender please make your comment as answer.I should paste actual code always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `aList` is not defined you should have received the error on `aList.append(p)` at the top of your loop before you get to `aList.append(k)` in try-except clause. Are you sure you don't have a typo?

```
aList = []
for p in anotherList:
  aList.append(p) # <== should have gotten error here first!
  try:
    k=p.someMethod()
    aList.append(k) #getting error here
  except someException:
    continue
 return aList
```

Comment: thanks.it was indeed a typo.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this code.

```
>>> anotherList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> aList = []
>>> for p in anotherList:
...     aList.append(p)
...     try:
...             aList.append(9)
...     except someException:
...             continue
... 
>>> aList
[1, 9, 2, 9, 3, 9, 4, 9, 5, 9]
```

As you can see, it works.

If you still have problems, please post more of your code, there's no error in the part you posted.